# Free book summary application usable on Linux

Tags: linux, information-management, web, books

The software that I require should be capable of:

- Document the main events and situations in my story;
- Link (in some or another way) characters to these events;
- Link descriptions, characteristics, etc to the characters;
- The software should be gratis;
- It´s a plus if it´s Open Source and;
- Should work in a Debian based GNU/Linux distribution or as a web platform

The main purpose of the software should be helping me to write the entire book and not have to think over and over again in the details of the world that I'm creating; just having them at hand so I can get the details from there and use those details to build my story in a coherent method.

---

I do not believe this post to be a duplicate of [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2269/software-for-managing-the-writing-of-a-book). The reason being:

- That question was made more than 3 years ago;
- Did not specify for which OS it would run on;
- What form the software would be used and;
- The OP didn't specify the software needing to be gratis/free or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Twine](https://twinery.org/) can work for you?

- open-source,
- free,
- runs on [Linux](https://bitbucket.org/klembot/twinejs/downloads/twine_2.1.3_linux64.zip) and in your [browser](https://twinery.org/2),
- enables you to document the main events of your story (you create a passage for each event),
- enables you to link characters (that are basically passages as well, you just name them as your characters and write descriptions).

This is a snippet of what a story organization can look like:
[image]

Another option worth a look (although not open-source and not 100% free as you can upgrade the basic version but don't have to) is [TheBrain](http://www.thebrain.com/products/thebrain/download-8/), which is also available on Linux.

- enables you to create visually beautiful links between scenes and characters,
- enables you to upload pictures to better visualize your characters.

Try either (or both) and see what better fits your flow.

Comment: OMG!!! Thank you so much!!! Honestly I had already lost any hope that this question would be ever answered. And, plus, Twine looks great! Thanks!